# What are the key factors or good practices that reduce the garbage collection time in Java?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, memory-management, garbage-collection

What are the key factors or good practices that reduce the garbage collection time in Java ?

All I know is increasing RAM could be one trick .

What are all the other features which effect it.

Comment: This depends on the characteristics of the garbage collector you are using.  Modern garbage collectors do well for short lived objects which is what most java programs have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple factors:

- the type of garbage collector used;
- collector configuration (e.g. the size of the various sub-heaps);
- the size and frequency of memory allocations;
- typical duration of object lifetime.

[Java Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137142528) by Hunt et al has some good material on optimizing Java GC for throughput and latency.

If you have a practical problem to solve, using a memory profiler on your program is often a good first step.